# A bare-bones DNS server

Tags: dns

I have to implement a DNS server in C and I don't know where to start. What are all the features that a DNS has...how can I implement a bare-bones DNS in single C file.

I don't even want to use a Database, just a file will work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not writing a full blown DNS so reading never ending RFC is a bit boring. Or is that absolutely essential?

Comment: What do you mean by bare-bones? Supporting nothing, but A lookups? :)

Comment: yes. I want a skeleton code which makes me understand kind of messages passed etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's big for homework! Your teacher is ambitious. Implementing DNS
requires reading at least ten complicated RFC (not mentioning DNSSEC...) Do
**not** limit yourself to RFC 1034 and 1035, there are **mandatory**
RFC after (such as 2181 and 2671). See a [nice graph](http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2010/05/24/436/) of them.

Is it an authoritative name server or a recursive one?

Do you have to do it from scratch? If not, I strongly suggest to start
with the [evldns](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/) library, which allows you to write an
anthoritative name server in 200 lines of C.

Otherwise, the usual advice applies: read source code (I suggest
[nsd](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/) for an authoritative server and [unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) for a recursive
one).

Answer (score 1):

[dns.net](http://www.dns.net/) points up [RFC 1034: DOMAIN NAMES - CONCEPTS AND FACILITIES](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc1034.txt) and [RFC 1035: DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc1035.txt) as the definitive references.

As a topical plus, wow your teacher by including some [non-ascii IDN](http://www.icann.org/en/topics/idn/factsheet-idn-fast-track-oct09-en.pdf) names in your toy lookup list.

Comment: These two RFC are *far* from being sufficient (2671, for instance, is really necessary today).

And IDN requires no support for the name server so it will be purely for the demo effect.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is a big spec.  If you really want DNS, use a DNS server.  So if you want something really quick and dirty, why not just write a program that edits your hosts file (C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts or /etc/hosts (on UNIX)?)

Answer (score 0):

The RFCs that the protocol is based on can be found here: http://www.zoneedit.com/doc/rfc/

There are also several explanations of the protocol that should be useful to be found around the internet, such as this one: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Understanding-DNS-Protocol-Part1.html

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

This example uses BSD sockets to build a simple DNS resolver.
 http://www.binarytides.com/blog/dns-query-code-in-c-with-winsock-and-linux-sockets/